# Bulk download of images from Flickr?

Tags: flickr, download, bulk-download

I want to retrieve some/most of my pictures from Flickr, lost a bunch when a drive went bad.  I can't find a way to easily download images other than one at a time.

I looked into something called Flickrfs but it didn't work and appears to no longer be maintained.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following apps to download multiple images from Flickr at once:

- [FlickrDown](http://blog.greggman.com/blog/flickrdown/)
- [Bulkr](http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr)
- [Downloadr](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2007/04/download-multiple-flickr-pictures-in.html)

Comment: Bulkr seemed the best of the bunch to me.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite tool for that is the Flickr Downloader. It's a desktop app that you can [download from here](http://download.cnet.com/Flickr-Downloader/3000-12512_4-10790953.html).